# "Select" tag in HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form name="form" action="https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks?" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<select>
<option value="258f2200948711e3b418a9a7">To-do</option>
<option value="258f220294b18a9a7">In progress</option>
<option value="258f2201948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7">Do today</option>
<option value="258f2203948711ea7" selected="selected">Done</option>
</select>             
<button id ="button" value="submit">create_task</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js ">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change',function() {
  alert( this.value );
});
});
</script>
```

We are trying to select the option from the list but its not working.
can anyone please help me

Comment: there is no select tag in your code. so $('select') is empty

Comment: I don't see `select` in your HTML! Code is fine!

Comment: Your code will work - just add the select element in HTML

Comment: where is your select??

Comment: Code block was wrong, edited it, so the select shows up.

Comment: You're better off to select using a ID

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/weEe9/

Comment: @Bobby Better to use an ID, i'm wondering why it would be better???

Comment: @A.Wolff Because now it implements on every select. Using an ID makes it unique for that specific select.

Comment: @KeesSonnema That's completly unrelevant to question

Comment: I either don't get why people start talking about ID's. It's working fine.

Comment: @A.Wolff You are right what I said was irrelevant and was more of a tip

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `script` element has both a `src` attribute and some content. It won’t work: the `src` attribute is used (and jQuery is loaded), but the content is ignored. See HTML 4.01 spec on [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1). (An HTML5 validator would issue a warning about this.) The solution is to use two `script` elements instead:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js ">
 </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log('setting up');
  $('select').on('change',function() {
    alert( this.value );
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 didn't see your answer before posting mine because of too much completly inaccurate other answers

Comment: I had pointed out the same but people like @KeesSonnema don't read the question properly and start downvoting the answers. Sad!

Comment: @Dipaks Ya, i see your deleted answer, really sad... Unfortunately, that's the way SO works... What a pity...

Comment: True! It's hard to understand why people are so excited to down vote the answers instead of posting one. @SridharR this is the main reason why good contributors are ignoring SO. Think.

Comment: thank u so much. what should i do to print the value of the option into an textbox?

Answer (score 0):

this have multiple answers

For single select dom elements, to get the currently selected value:

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the selected option's text, use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function () {
        // use .find() to get the selected option and then get the text it contains.
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").html()); /*Replace with .text() if it doesn't yield desired results*/ 
    });
});
```

Or else, if you need to get its `value` attribute's value, use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/HQSjc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
<form name="form" action="https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks?" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <select>
            <option value="258f2200948711e3b418a9a7">To-do</option>
            <option value="258f220294b18a9a7">In progress</option>
            <option value="258f2201948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7">Do today</option>
            <option value="258f2203948711ea7" selected="selected">Done</option>
        </select>
        <button id="button" value="submit">create_task</button>
    </form>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function () {
        alert($('select'));
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/b57Lc/4/

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to see which select option is selected you use this code

```
<select id="selectlistid">
   <option value="whoa">WHOA!</option>
   <option value="huh">HUH?</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getlistvalue()
    {
    return document.getElementById('selectlistid').options[document.getElementById('selectlistid').selectedIndex].value;
    }
</script>
```

you need to remeber to use the selectedIndex value to get the right options element to get the actual value of that option.